# MediaWiki Vector.css line-height not working

Tags: mediawiki

I apply the following changes to Vector.css

```
html,body,p,td,a,li,content { 
line-height: 1.3em;
font-size: 200%;
}
```

The font-size property works while the line-height remains unchanged. I have used the  tag directly in the wiki itself and that way the line-height property works. However, I want to change line-height for the entire wiki in Vector.css but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my above question is to use

```
#bodyContent { 
font-size: 110%;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

This changes the line width, line-height or space between the lines of your WIKI. It seems that the code I posted in my question can be used to change the font-size of ALL elements in your WIKI including the bodyContent. However, the same code cannot be used to change the line-height of bodyContent. For that you will need the extra piece above which I put into Common.css but it should work as well in Vector.css .